# Where should business validation to be done

Tags: java, jakarta-ee

Suppose the architecture is such that there is

1. Struts framework or jersey resource
2. Facade layer
3. Business layer
4. Data access object layer DAO

Though the Input field validation is to be done at presentation layer i.e Struts Action class or jersey resource class

But my question is where should business level validation to be done and same outcome to be passed to UI.

I.e suppose resource is

employee/{employeeId} method DELETE

Now first need to verify that employeeId exist or not , so for that validation should be done at resource level, facade level or business level and how it should be any best practice is highly appreciated.

Also please note that this business validation require DAO layer access since to check in DB if employeeId really exist.

Thanks in advance

Comment: This is a business function.

Answer (score 0):

There are as many arguments as approaches for what you're asking.  I prefer to leave validation to the business layer and let the service layers above that more or less just handle routing and error reporting.  Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Depends on the architectures and frameworks you have choosen.

In example: If you have one Database but a server-farm, the Validation should be more near the Database. If you can lock/unlock the Database in the DAO, you shall lock the employee-row first before you validate.

Also it depends on the configuration:

- If you use optimistic or pessimistic locking.
- If you have a @version field on the entitys.
- many many more.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to write logic related database access at dao layer, which returns the result to service layer and it returns to the Action class. And you should validate it in your action class.